# Repost - JavaScrpt split line Regex - 'double quote' inside 'double-quotes'

Tags: javascript, regex, split, double-quotes

I'm so sorry if I missed details on the 1st post which is closed. I added comma within double quotes to the string, and I added the string into variable. I cannot simply split on comma.

**Original Post**

Basically, I need to split a line into an array. But I encountered error when 'double quote' inside 'double quotes'. The sample line is like this:

```
var line = '"123","str","456",8/10/2021 7:44:47 AM,"str","str","str","","str","str",0,"789",1,"101112","Ironman"s, iPhone","+131415",30'
```

"123","str","456",8/10/2021 7:44:47 AM,"str","str","str","","str","str",0,"789",1,"101112","Ironman"s, iPhone","+131415",30
My current regex is:

```
values = line.split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/g);
```

My testing tool is https://regexr.com/, and I'm not sure how to create a colored explain graph which I saw other's post. If you could point out as well please.

If I remove the double quote inside to "Ironman s, iPhone', my regex works well, but it's a big headache now as I cannot find a working way to handle.

Comment: What does the resulting array look like?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You just needed to replace the `$` with `(?:,|$)` because at every `,` split position there won't necessarily be an even number of double quotes to the end of the line.

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*(?:,|$))
```

For example,

```js
const line = '"123","str","456",8/10/2021 7:44:47 AM,"str","str","str","","str","str",0,"789",1,"101112","Ironman"s, iPhone","+131415",30';

const values = line.split(/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*(?:,|$))/g);

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Dear MikeM, Thank you sir! This works well. Thank you so much for the help! And I believe your answer would help many other too :) Thanks again!